# Android app failed to load native library

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I had add the .so file into my project, the path is 'src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libAndroidIDCard.so'. The APK file is already contain this library at 'lib/armeabi/libAndroidIDCard.so'.

I load this library as follows:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("AndroidIDCard");
}
```

but got an 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load AndroidIDCard from loader' Exception.

Why?

I have solved by add a 'armeabi-v7a' folder and put the '.so' file into it.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to run your APK on an x86 device or emulator? If that's the case, it will not work.

Comment: Do you see this library file at device/emulator? Is this lib compiled for your architecture?

Comment: @Dalmas thank you! It was available on my device. It becomes unavailable when I updated the source code from svn. I don't know why~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by add a 'armeabi-v7a' folder and put the '.so' file into it.